# everything after --

Tags: php, regex

```
-- المصدر : <a href="http://www.almasryalyoum.com/node/799626">المصري اليوم</a>
```

i want to edit this code to remove everything after --

the code

```
function remove_first_moret ($content) {
if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
$content = preg_replace("/-(.*)$/", "", $content, 1);
} return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_moret');
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? It already strips anything after the first hyphen. Just make it two hyphens if that's what you want.

Comment: What is the  definition of "after" in the context of a right-to-left script?

Comment: Whats wrong with `/(?<=--).*/s, ""` ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex. Use **[`strstr()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)**

```
strstr($string, "--", true);
```

Comment: nice but doesn't `strstr` remove '--' itself?

Comment: @tosin: It does, but in which case, all you need to do is add it again. Beats regex in performance and readability any day.

Comment: I see. agree about regex. smart idea

Comment: can anyone add the code after this edit as i don't know how to edit it